# Android Scroll to ID on the same page

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've scoured google for an example on scrolling to an element by ID on the same page but to no success. I was wondering how it would be done with the following example?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button 
       android:id="@+id/pressMe"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:text="Press me to scroll to A">

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/scrollToMe"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_marginTop="2000dp"
       android:background="#f00">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can focus on that view and, I think, it'll autoscroll to it.

I believe you can also get coordinates of the view you need  and scrollTo to them.